# How to solve TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I have submit form then I am getting a Error. You can view Error Related Token Mismatch Exception.

How to solve

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67: error

I have already added token Variable.

```
<input name="_token" value="dZfqvG7m1G0TGtXtWkDoWFXs5wqIwH86mMzCKfTy" type="hidden">
```

Is there any other solution for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TokenMismatchException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427840/laravel-tokenmismatchexception)

Comment: Can you show us the request data you send? It should have a _token in it.

Comment: <form id="search-page" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="POST" action="casino-games" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="_token" value="6YUHwEexn9WbM5U1hFdkVRlZIAKa6jkaa1HWgqHK" type="hidden">
<input id="game_search" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Game Search" name="game_search" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit" title="Search">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
</button>
</form>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel TokenMismatchException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427840/laravel-tokenmismatchexception)

Comment: The HTML is not needed, what you actually need to understand if _token is passed is to look in your Developers Console and find the request data.

Comment: I have do print_r on this function but it's not go on this page getting Direct Error

Comment: Did you really use `<input name="_token" value="dZfqvG7m1G0TGtXtWkDoWFXs5wqIwH86mMzCKfTy" type="hidden">` or an `csrf_field()` or `csrf_token()`?

Comment: @DestinatioN 
Yes I have use this hidden token Variable. But I can't view when form submit

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `session.php` file in the config folder. Maybe the path of your laravel installation is incorrect.

Also try to check if your application has write access to the session directory.

```
chmod 777 ./storage/framework/sessions
```

The CSRF token works by flashing the value to your session, then comparing the value with what was submitted with your form on the next request. If your sessions are not being set then this will always fail.

note: Just clearing the browser cookies works as well sometimes ;)

**If you're using AJAX POST dont forget to add the following**

in your head section:

```
< meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

in your javascript section:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
});
```

Comment: I have give Permission to this session folder and Remove Browser Cache and Cookies. But still getting Same issue

Comment: Did u also checked if the value's in the session.php file are correct? Also try resetting your application key by using this command `php artisan key:generate`.

Comment: I have already do this also do composer Update but still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue.

I am using Session_driver=file (.env file)

Clear session data: 
Delete all files in storage/frameworks/sessions/

Artisan clear cache: 
php artisan cache:clear

Restart apache in ubuntu: 
Sudo service apache2 restart

Clear browser cache in chrome or another browser you are using

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file:

```
 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

add 'POST' to

```
  protected function isReading($request)
    {
        return in_array($request->method(), ['HEAD', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST']);
    }
```