# Post request from another domain results TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with a bank api.

The bank send a post request to my website but does not return there is not a token field is their request and I am faced with `TokenMismatchException`.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is coresponding codes:

```
public function submitPayment()
{  
    $api = 'test';
    $amount = '3443354';
    $redirect = URL::to('new-order/after-payment');
    $result = $this->send($api, $amount, $redirect);
    $result = json_decode($result);

    return redirect("https://example.com/$result->transId");
}
```

Comment: You can disable CSRF token check by adding the route in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file in except array

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427840/laravel-tokenmismatchexception/32125744#32125744

Comment: @AkshayKhale Thank you

Comment: Check the posted answer, that is more useful for your case

Comment: @AkshayKhale, Your comment was more useful in my case :)

Comment: great that I could help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short you want to rename the default `_token` as CSRF token field name of Laravel to something else for that,

You can Override function **Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken@tokensMatch();** from **App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken** Class and change the CSRF parameter name.

You can add following code in your **App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken** file.

```
   /**
     * Determine if the session and input CSRF tokens match.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function tokensMatch($request)
    {
        $sessionToken = $request->session()->token();

        $token = $request->input('_csrf_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

        if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
            $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
        }

        if (! is_string($sessionToken) || ! is_string($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        return hash_equals($sessionToken, $token);
    }
```

In above function CSRF field is changed to `_csrf_token` from `_token`